# How can I create a new PSDrive by using a password that is not SystemSecuredString?

Tags: .net, powershell

Is there a way to create a New-PSDrive by using a password that is a NON- SystemSecured string ?

If the password is "FooBoo" I want to use it as it is...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

just use the old net use commmand

```
PS>net use z: \\server\share Fooboo /user:domain\user
PS>Get-PSDrive -Name Z

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                CurrentLoc
                                                                                              ation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                ----------
Z                 150,36         49,64 FileSystem    Z:\
```

Or convert you plain text password to secure-string :

```
PS>$pass="FooBoo"|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
PS>$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('user@domain',$pass)
PS>New-PSDrive -name j -Root \\server\share -Credential $cred -PSProvider filesystem

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
j                                      FileSystem    \\server\share
```